# Can't iterate over my own object

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and can't figure this out.  I am trying to make an object from a `json` feed.  I am trying to basically make a dictionary for each item in the json fed that has every property. The error I get is either `TypeError: 'mediaObj' object is not subscriptable` or not `iterable`

For bonus points, the array has many sub dictionaries too.  What I would like is to be able to access that nested data as well.

Here is my code:

```
url = jsonfeedwithalotofdata.com
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = instagramData.read()
data = instagramData.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(data)
media = data['data']

class mediaObj:
    def __init__(self, item):
        for key in item:
            setattr(self, key, item[key])
            print(self[key])

    def run(self):
        return self['id']

for item in media:
    mediaPiece = mediaObj(item)
```

This would come from a `json` feed that looks as follows (so data is the array that comes after "data"):

```
"data": [
{
"attribution": null,
"videos": {},
"tags": [],
"type": "video",
"location": null,
"comments": {},
"filter": "Normal",
"created_time": "1407423448461",
"link": "http://instagram.com/p/rabdfdIw9L7D-/",
"likes": {},
"images": {},
"users_in_photo": [],
"caption": {},
"user_has_liked": true,
"id": "782056834879232959294_1051813051",
"user": {}
}
```

So my hope was that I could create an object for every item in the array, and then I could, for instance, say:

```
print(mediaPiece['id'])
```

or even better

```
print(mediaPiece['comments'])
```

And see a list of comments. Thanks a million

Comment: Think about what would happen if there was an key of `"run"` in the json feed.

Comment: A. It will not.
B. I did....nothing comes to mind

Comment: A. Will not _ever_? Can you be really sure? The same problem applies to any of your attributes you might add to the class in the future being overwritten  in the instance. I guess it's a nice bit of "job security" B. It will replace your `run` method and lead to lots of fun bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a problem because you're using attributes to store your data items, but using list/dictionary lookup syntax to try to retrieve them.

Instead of `print(self[key])`, use `print(getattr(self, key))`, and instead of `return self['id']` use `return self.id`.